# ¿Se le puede añadir un onclick a un elemento dentro de <label>? (concretamente a un "data-off")

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo este codigo, que muestra dos "botones" (realmente no son botones, pero "data-off" y "data-on" simulan dos botones)

```html
<span class="toggle">
              <input type="checkbox">
              <label data-off="Contact me" data-on="Maybe&nbsp; next &nbsp; time"></label>
          </span>
```

Claro, la funcionalidad hasta ahora está hecha con CSS:

```css
.toggle {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background-color:#bbb;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-align:center;
}

.toggle input {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.toggle label {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:1px;
  right:1px;
  bottom:4px;
  left:1px;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 -1px 1px #888,
    inset 0 -5px 1px #bbb,
    inset 0 -6px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 -1px 1px #888,
    inset 0 -5px 1px #bbb,
    inset 0 -6px 0 white;
  box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 -1px 1px #888,
    inset 0 -5px 1px #bbb,
    inset 0 -6px 0 white;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color:#171717;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 white;
  cursor:text;
}

.toggle label:before {
  content:attr(data-off);
  position:absolute;
  top:6px;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:4;
}

.toggle label:after {
  content:attr(data-on);
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:11px;
  left:0;
  color:#666;
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #eee;
}

.toggle input:checked + label {
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
}

.toggle input:checked:hover + label {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
}

.toggle input:checked + label:before {
  z-index:1;
  top:11px;
}

.toggle input:checked + label:after {
  bottom:9px;
  color:#aaa;
  text-shadow:none;
  z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<span class="toggle">
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <label data-off="Contact me" data-on="Maybe&nbsp; next &nbsp; time"></label>
              </span>
```

Pero yo quería ahora añadir más funcionalidad. Añadir algo así como un evento onClick a `data-off="Contact me"`

Os muestro el jsfiddle completo:

https://jsfiddle.net/3vs628bp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He asociado un *event handler* al evento click (se puede usar `onclick`, pero en general me parece una mala costumbre).
Como puedes ver, funciona sin problemas.

Realmente no hay un elemento `off`, **es un pseudo-elemento y no está presente en el DOM**, así que en mi ejemplo leo los valores `data-...` del label y elijo según el estado actual.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#contact');
const label = input.nextElementSibling;
input.addEventListener('click',() => {
  data= label.dataset
   if (input.checked) {
    console.log(data.on);
   } else {
    console.log(data.off);
   }
});
```

```css
.toggle {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background-color:#bbb;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:4px;
  text-align:center;
}

.toggle input {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 0;
  padding:0 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.toggle label {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:1px;
  right:1px;
  bottom:4px;
  left:1px;
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top,#fff 0%,#ddd 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 -1px 1px #888,
    inset 0 -5px 1px #bbb,
    inset 0 -6px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 -1px 1px #888,
    inset 0 -5px 1px #bbb,
    inset 0 -6px 0 white;
  box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 -1px 1px #888,
    inset 0 -5px 1px #bbb,
    inset 0 -6px 0 white;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius:3px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color:#171717;
  text-shadow:0 1px 0 white;
  cursor:text;
}

.toggle label:before {
  content:attr(data-off);
  position:absolute;
  top:6px;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:4;
}

.toggle label:after {
  content:attr(data-on);
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:11px;
  left:0;
  color:#666;
  text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #eee;
}

.toggle input:checked + label {
  background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  background-image:linear-gradient(top,#eee 0%,#ccc 50%,#fff 50%,#eee 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  box-shadow:0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
}

.toggle input:checked:hover + label {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
  box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
    inset 0 1px 7px -1px #ccc,
    inset 0 5px 1px #fafafa,
    inset 0 6px 0 white;
}

.toggle input:checked + label:before {
  z-index:1;
  top:11px;
}

.toggle input:checked + label:after {
  bottom:9px;
  color:#aaa;
  text-shadow:none;
  z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<span class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" id="contact">
  <label  data-off="Contact me" data-on="Maybe&nbsp; next &nbsp; time"></label>
</span>
```